# Based on one Textbox the other textboxes will autofill with data from multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform that is pulling data from more than one worksheet based on the entry into the first textbox("Number"). So far I have been able to get it to enter data from one worksheet but not the other.
My Userform ("LineView") has the following Textboxes:
**Number** - this is the one that I enter a Job Number(eg. "J1234") and based on that it populates the others.
These ones pull from Worksheet("Jobs")
**JobName** - This is pulled from Column 2
**CustomerName** - This is pulled from Column 3
**Address** - Column 7
**DeliveryInstructions** - Column 8
**Contact** - Column 5
**ContactPhone** - Column 6
The rest pull from Worksheet("Doors")
The code that I have written for the Textboxes that take data from Worksheet("Doors") have been working. I am only having issues with pulling information from the Worksheet("Jobs").
This is the code that I have written so far.

```
Private Sub Number_Change()
   Dim j As Worksheet
   Dim d As Worksheet
   Set j = Sheets("Jobs")
   Set d = Sheets("Doors")
   Dim LR As Long
   Dim r As Long
   Dim i As Long
   DoorList.Clear
    With Worksheets("Doors")
    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    For r = 2 To LR
        If .Cells(r, 5).Value = Number.Value Then
            DoorList.AddItem .Cells(r, 1).Value
            DoorList.List(i, 0) = .Cells(r, 1).Value
            DoorList.List(i, 1) = .Cells(r, 2).Value
            DoorList.List(i, 2) = .Cells(r, 4).Value
            DoorList.List(i, 3) = .Cells(r, 6).Value
            DoorList.List(i, 4) = .Cells(r, 7).Value
            DoorList.List(i, 5) = .Cells(r, 15).Value
            i = i + 1
End If
Next r
End With
With DoorList
.ColumnCount = 6

'Fill Time Cells
Jbox.Value = Application.SumIf(d.Range("E:E"), Number.Value, d.Range("H:H"))
DMBox.Value = Application.SumIf(d.Range("E:E"), Number.Value, d.Range("I:I"))
SBox.Value = Application.SumIf(d.Range("E:E"), Number.Value, d.Range("J:J"))
PHBox.Value = Application.SumIf(d.Range("E:E"), Number.Value, d.Range("K:K"))
CDBox.Value = Application.SumIf(d.Range("E:E"), Number.Value, d.Range("L:L"))
CJBox.Value = Application.SumIf(d.Range("E:E"), Number.Value, d.Range("M:M"))
COBox.Value = Application.SumIf(d.Range("E:E"), Number.Value, d.Range("N:N"))

End Sub
```

I have tried many different ways but cannot get any to work.

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any code there which pulls info from "Jobs", so it's hard to say what the problem might be.

Comment: I have entered what I thought was one of the ways I was doing that part previously and just tested it and it worked!!!? I don't know what I have different from other times!? This is what I have now entered and is working:

Comment: 'Fill in Job Details
         With Worksheets("Jobs")
        For r = 2 To LR
            If .Cells(r, 1).Value = Number.Value Then
            JobName.Value = .Cells(r, 2)
            CustomerName.Value = .Cells(r, 3)
            Address.Value = .Cells(r, 7)
            DeliveryInstructions.Value = .Cells(r, 8)
            Contact.Value = .Cells(r, 5)
            ContactPhone.Value = .Cells(r, 6)
            End If
          Next r
         End With